# Usage of "on cloud nine"?

Tags: idioms, usage, expressions, formality

I heard "*I'm **on cloud nine***" in a song and realized it was an expression by reading it somewhere else.
I am learning English for years but I never heard of that before. I found informations about the **meaning*** and **etymology****, *but* I was wondering:

- Is it a common expression ?
- Would it sound old or from elevated language ?
- **How would you use it ?**

* I found different explanations, always talking about an extreme happiness
** 1. Cloud classification by the US Weather Bureau in the 1950s. 2. one of the stages to enlightenment of a Bodhisattva (Buddhism)

Comment: The origin of the [relatively recent **on cloud nine**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+cloud+nine&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20cloud%20nine%3B%2Cc0) is uncertain, so anything we might say here about that is effectively a matter of opinion. But as you can see from that chart, it's *still* gaining currency (in informal contexts), so you can use it anywhere you might use ***in seventh heaven*** (or as a "toned down" version of ***as happy as a pig in shit***, say).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks I'll remember. I understand more the meaning as we have the same expression (as happy as a pig in shit) in French.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Is it a common expression?**

In my experience of 30 years living in the UK, yes, somewhat common. You'd certainly be understood by the majority of UK residents if you used it.

> **Would it sound old or from elevated language?**

I don't believe so, it's probably a less commonly used phrase than it might have been 5, 10 or 15 years ago (or more), but it's not antiquated or historical in nature.

> **How would you use it?**

Something like:

> We just had our first child last week. We're both on cloud 9.

Comment: I think your example at the end is quite good. The expression generally expresses elation rather than mere contentment (whereas the *happy as a pig in muck* expression talked about in the comments probably wouldn't be used by parents of a newborn).

Answer (score 3):

[The origin of the phrase is not clear.](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/on-cloud-nine.html)

In any case, it's a somewhat old-fashioned expression.  I don't hear it all that often anymore, although it might appear as a reference, like the name of a business where you go to feel particularly happy (like a day spa).

Should you use it?  I don't see why not.  The worst that can happen is, in the wrong context, it might be unintentionally humorous.